# Can costs orders be made against a party’s solicitors instead of the party itself?

Tags: england-and-wales, costs

Alice retains Solomon’s solicitors to defend her in a claim brought against Barbara. Solomon is granted the discretion and initiative of deciding how to respond to the correspondence that partly forms the proceedings.

Yet Solomon does so in the most unreasonable, counterproductive and petty way in his obligatorily opposing every last point and request of Barbara’s as a matter of course, creating greatly more work for both Barbara and the court. This forms the basis of an application by Barbara for a costs order in her favour.

Now if the unreasonable conduct by Solomon if admittedly on Alice’s behalf was undertaken yet on his own initiative, would costs orders in these circumstances ever be issued against Solomon or his firm, or only ever against the party he represents (so in this case Alice)?

Answer (score 1):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

*Quebec (Director of Criminal and Penal Prosecutions) v. Jodoin*, [2017 SCC 26, paras. 25, 29](https://canlii.ca/t/h3q0c#par25);

> [25] While the courts do have the power to award costs against a lawyer personally, the threshold for exercising it is a high one. ...

> [29] ... an award of costs against a lawyer personally can be justified only on an exceptional basis where the lawyer’s acts have seriously undermined the authority of the courts or seriously interfered with the administration of justice. This high threshold is met where a court has before it an unfounded, frivolous, dilatory or vexatious proceeding that denotes a serious abuse of the judicial system by the lawyer, or dishonest or malicious misconduct on his or her part, that is deliberate. Thus, a lawyer may not knowingly use judicial resources for a purely dilatory purpose with the sole objective of obstructing the orderly conduct of the judicial process in a calculated manner.